# Strange date format conversion in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a variable with date string

```
> $str
5 november 2012 y. 18:24:13
```

When I'm trying to remove spaces from it I get another string in another format

```
> $str  -replace " ",""
05.11.201218:24:13
```

How to explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original `$str` variable is a DateTime object. When you try to replace that, it converts it to a string, and then it removes the spaces. Ex.

```
PS > $date = [DateTime]::Now

PS > $date

#DateTime object
30. januar 2013 12:24:09

PS > $date.ToString()
#Converts it to string
30.01.2013 12:24:09

PS > $date -replace " ",""
#Converts it to string and removes spaces
30.01.201312:24:09
```

If you wanted to have the first format(datetime format) without spaces, try:

```
PS > $date.ToString("F").Replace(" ","")
30.januar201312:24:09
```

More about DateTime string-formats, [head over to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)